# Developer option missing in Setting menu ios9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9.1

Yesterday i updated my `iphone5s` to `ios9.1` with help of `ipsw` file. Now I am not able to see `Developer option` in `Setting menu`. I want to check my application in `Low Connectivity` situation.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy now,

You need to attach your iOS Device with Mac  and select trust option in device.

Then open Xcode and select attached iOS Device . You will automatically get Developer options under Settings App.

I am using current Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Download Hardware IO Tools for Xcode from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

And there's Network Link Conditioner app, which can help to simulate low connectivity, so you can test your app in Simulator.